# Print elements of a list into binary tree format

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this list:

```
numbers = [9,4,6,5,2,3]
```

I am wondering how can I print the elements of that list in this format:

```
     09
    /   \
  04     06
 /  \   /  \
05  [] 02  03
```

- The element that always misses is the right child of the **root's left
  child**, returning an empty list `[]`
- In all cases the input list has 6 elements, that is, the tree has 3 levels (root + first level + second level)

I have seen another similar questions where the solution was given using `Linked Lists` or simple `Nodes`, but at this time I can only use a simple list

I have only tried printing all the elements like this:

```
for elem in numbers:
  print(elem)
```

The problem I have is that I don't know how to print  `/` and `\` in a proper way

**Additional information**

1. Yes, it is about hard-code it all. It can be a similar format, not necessarily the same number of spaces between the elements, etc
2. It is an exercise and I can't use another structures, only a list
3. There's no context since it is an exercise. It is about finding a way to get that results (print the elements of the list in that way)

Comment: The way to do this *is* to use another structure to build up the data in the requisite format. If your teacher told you to do this without using any data structures, then that person is not a very good teacher. That's like asking engineering students to build something without using a screwdriver. Sure, I *can* drive all the screws with a steady hand, but doing so doesn't really teach me anything of value, and I'm just going to have to unlearn it later.

Comment: I totally agree. It seems that structures like linked lists, etc are seen later. So at this moment it is about reproducing that example with proper prints. I don't know if it is clearer now.

Comment: A `list` is a suitable data structure for a **complete** binary tree (filled from left to right on the last level), but then the visualization is not the representation of your example `list`.

Comment: If I have undestood well, you say that there's a missing [] in the list, right?. Yeah I also do not understand why the example is that horrible. The [] has to be added in the visualization (always in that exact position).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
numbers = [9, 4, 6, 5, 2, 3]

def format_numbers(numbers):
    out = []
    for n in numbers: 
        fn = str(n) if len(str(n)) > 1 else f"0{n}"
        out.append(fn)
    return out

numbers = format_numbers(numbers)

print(f"\n        {numbers[0]}")
print("      /    \\")
print(f"    {numbers[1]}      {numbers[2]}")
print("   /  \\    /  \\")
print(f"  {numbers[3]}  []  {numbers[4]}  {numbers[5]}")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list=[9,4,6,5,2,3]
print(f"""
       {str(list[0]).zfill(2)}
     /   \\
    {str(list[1]).zfill(2)}    {str(list[2]).zfill(2)}
   /  \   / \\
  {str(list[3]).zfill(2)}  [] {str(list[4]).zfill(2)}  {str(list[5]).zfill(2)}""")
```

Because you say you can only use list method , This is the solution (If format string is not allowed , just turn all `{` and `}` to `,`)